# Json on input instead of autocomplet

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$('#lev_nr').on('input', {
source: function(request, response) {
$.ajax({
url : 'pallavvikelse/jsonData',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        name_startsWith: request.term,
                type: 'lev_table',
                row_num : 1
        },
        success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
        var code = item.split("|");
                return {
                label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                }
        }));
        }
});
},
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
                $('#lev_namn').val(names[1]);
                var txt = $('#avta').val(names[2]);
                if (txt.val() == "ja"){
        $('#t').hide();

        }

    } }).trigger('input');
```

Can someone see why this does not work?
I am trying to change autocomplete function to `on.input` but I can't get it to work.
The code works perfectly when i change the first line to  `$('#leverantors_nr').autocomplete({`
and when I remove `.trigger('input')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#lev_nr').on('input', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'pallavvikelse/jsonData',
        data: {
            name_startsWith: this.value,
            type: 'country_table',
            row_num: 1
        }, 
        dataType: 'json',    
        success: function(data) {


             alert(data);
    var names = data.split('|');

 alert(names[0]);

        }
    });



});
```

I have managed to make it work this far, but when i try to alert(names[0]) i get nothing when alert(data) i get resault.. The data i get loocks like this: 5000950|TEST|BLABLA
Wen i try to split and alert again it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#leverantors_nr').on('input', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'pallavvikelse/jsonData',
        data: {
            name_startsWith: this.value,
            type: 'country_table',
            row_num: 1
        }, 
        dataType: 'json',    
        success: function(data) {

      alert(data.lev_namn);

        }
    });


});
```

Problem solved:
i changed the database so it outputs array like this:

```
  $arr['lev_nr'] = $row->lev_nr; 
  $arr['lev_namn'] = $row->lev_namn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not properly parsing JSON data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse